# how to calculate MTD in R for a different month

Tags: r, difftime

The task is to find number of days in MTD for two months, the month that had highest inflow numbers (July) in my case and the present month. 
Because I plan to run the statement as a script everyday, I don't want to hardcode anything.

The dataframe is like this:

```
SERVICE              BEST MONTH TOTAL    BEST MONTH MTD  CURR. MONTH MTD
No of Working Days
..
..
..
```

For "BEST MONTH TOTAL", I used following statement:

```
report[1,2] <- sum(!weekdays(seq(as.Date('2019-07-01'), as.Date('2019-07- 
31'), 'days')) %in% c('Sunday','Saturday'))
```

For current month no of days MTD, the number of days I calculated using:

```
difftime(Sys.Date(),'2019-09-01',units = "days" )
```

This gives the output:

```
Time difference of 12.22917 days
```

Is there a way that I can get just the interger 12?

And how do I calculate BEST MONTH MTD? Is there a function that'll help go back to same date as sys.date() in the month of July to calculate number of working days MTD? 
i.e. essentially what I need is:

```
difftime('2019-07-13','2019-07-01', units = "days")
```

But don't want to hardcode '2019-07-13' as I want to run this as a script and want to avoid changing date every day. Also I just need the difference in integer without "Time difference of ... days".

Comment: What is MTD ? Also for me it is unclear what input you are going to enter and what output you expect.

Comment: Month To Date, I need to calculate number of working days from 1st of the month. For example today is 13th of Sept, so total number of days in the current month is 12. I need to do that same for the month of July. i.e. difftime('2019-07-13', '2019-07-01', unites = "days"), but I don't want to hardcode '2019-07-13'. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert to the number of days, as a numeric:

```
as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),'2019-09-01',units = "days" ))
```

Comment: Wanted to know if there's another function, anyway it works. How about next part of question? How to go back to same day in July as current Sys.Date()

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```r
trunc(difftime(Sys.Date(),'2019-09-01',units = "days"))
#output
#Time difference of 12 days

best_month_mtd <- function(y) {
  trunc(difftime(Sys.Date(),y, units = "days"))
}

#typical usage
best_month_mtd('2019-09-01')
#output
#Time difference of 12 days
```

That should give you what you want.

## Update

If you just want to compute the number of days elapsed from the start date of the month, a one liner using `lubridate` might be handy. This might be different from the actual number of working days. The later requires handling days closed by a calendar in an organization as well as national holidays.

```r
library(lubridate)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#The start date of the month can be computed using floor_date() from lubridate 
#floor_date() takes a date-time object and rounds it down to the nearest 
#boundary of the specified time unit.
month_start <- floor_date(Sys.Date(), "month")
month_start
#"2019-09-01"
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#difftime between Sys.Date() and month_start
difftime(Sys.Date(),month_start, units = "days")
#Time difference of 12 days
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# to print only the number of days 
paste0(trunc(difftime(Sys.Date(),month_start, units = "days")))
#"12"
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Using the above a one liner can be constructed follows. 
paste0(trunc(difftime(Sys.Date(),floor_date(Sys.Date(), "month"), units = "days")))
```

Comment: in the function best_month_mdt("2019-07-13", "2019-07-01"), I don't want to hardcode "2019-07-13", because I need to keep changing that every day. Is there a function that I can use instead.

Comment: passing `Sys.Date()` as `arglist` can work. See my edit.